# How can I make this code shorter and resizable?

Tags: java, eclipse

So the assignment was to "Write a method to make a diamond like pattern with numbers. Your program should be resizable and look like as follows:"

```
    1
   222
  33333
 4444444
555555555
 4444444
  33333
   222
    1
```

My code is the following and **cannot** be resized (it doesn't add an additional lines of numbers as asked in the assignment, I couldn't figure out how to do that). Any help?

```
public class task2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    upperDiamond();
    lowerDiamond();
    
    }

public static void upperDiamond( ) {
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for ( int a = 5 - i; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        System.out.println("1");
        
        for ( int a = 4 - i; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        for ( int b = 0; b <= 2; b++) {
            System.out.print("2");
        }
        
        for ( int a = 3 - i; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        

        for ( int a = 3 - i; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        for ( int c = 0; c <= 4; c ++) {
            System.out.print("3");
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        for ( int a = 2 - i; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        for (int d = 0; d <= 6; d ++) {
            System.out.print("4");
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        for ( int a = i - 1; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        for ( int e = 0; e <= 8; e++) {
            System.out.print("5");
        }
    }
}
public static void lowerDiamond() {
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        
        for ( int a = 2 - i; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        for (int d = 0; d <= 6; d ++) {
            System.out.print("4");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for ( int a = 3 - i; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        for ( int c = 0; c <= 4; c ++) {
            System.out.print("3");
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        for ( int a = 4 - i; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        for ( int b = 0; b <= 2; b++) {
            System.out.print("2");
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        for ( int a = 5 - i; a > 0; a--) {
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("1");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: create a reusable method. But SO is not an appropriate place for code review.

Comment: Don't use individual code blocks for each of the lines/numbers but think of an algorithm to determine how many spaces and numbers to write on a single given line. Basic approach: input the number of lines, for each line (outer loop) print the appropriate number of spaces (increasing until the center, then decreasing) and numbers (also increasing and decreasing). For each line only 2 nested loops should be necessary: 1 for printing the spaces and 1 for printing the digits. - Tip for dermining the algorithm: look at the loops you already have for each line and how variables change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a more generic way like this:

```
public static void printDiamond(int n) {
    int numberOfSpaces = n-1;
    int numberOfItems = 1;
    
    //upper diamond
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfSpaces; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfItems; j++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        numberOfSpaces--;
        numberOfItems+=2;
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    //lower diamond
    numberOfSpaces = 1;
    numberOfItems -= 4; 
    for(int i = n-1; i >= 1; i--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfSpaces; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfItems; j++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        numberOfSpaces++;
        numberOfItems-=2;
        System.out.println();
    }
        
}
```